# Implementing Oauth2 login, Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am updating my website's login system from LightOpenID to Google's Oauth 2.0.

When I require the Client.php and the Service/Oauth2.php I get an error

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/myname/repos/website_current/lib/google-api-php-client/src/Google/Service/Oauth2.php on line 32

The code I am using (from my login.php file) looks like this

```
require_once(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/lib/autoload.php');
require('Google/Client.php');
require('Google/Service/Oauth2.php');
echo "exit";
exit();
```

I have added the include path in the PHP.ini (in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini) as

```
include_path = ".:/usr/local/lib/php:/home/myname/repos/website_current/lib/google-api-php-client/src"
```

So its seems my Oauth2.php file can't see any of the other includes including the class 'Google_Service' which is one folder up in 'Service.php'.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
lib/
... autoload.php
... functions.php
... google-api-php-client/
    ... src/
        ... Google/ (etc etc)
public_html/
... login/
    ...login.php
```

I have no idea why this is occuring. The include path should be seen, and shows up as an included path using phpinfo(); Can someone please give me some insight?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Make sure you add the line *BEFORE* any other Google "require_once" lines.

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';
```

I had it last and it had me scratching my head for a good 10 minutes.

Comment: autoload.php has been moved -- now use:
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';

Answer (score 3):

Per the instruction on [github](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client):

`require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php'; // or wherever autoload.php is located`

In your case it seems like the above include url should work fine.

Comment: I also have required autoload.php. Forgot to add it into the code above (See above edits). Is autoload meant to be in a specfiic place? Maybe the Oauth2.php file cant load classes properly?

Answer (score 2):

The new way of doing this (circa early 2016) is

```
require_once("Google/autoload.php");
```

(Assuming you have already set your include path to have /path/to/google-api-php-client/src)

Comment: Not sure if you will see this but I get this error when I add the autoload This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. Do I not already have the full package?

Answer (score 2):

As of Nov 2016

```
require_once ... 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: As per the official instructions, you are right but this is not working for me. They make it so complex!

Answer (score 1):

To this version https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client this is  a posible solution

```
set_include_path("google-api-php-client/src/" . PATH_SEPARATOR . get_include_path());

//.....

require_once 'Google/Service.php';
//.....
```

Answer (score 1):

While working with Google API integration

> Fatal error: Class 'abc' not found

error comes when there is definitely something different between the library you have in `composer.json` above, and the library that is actually being auto-loaded.

had same problem just changed in my `composer.json`

```
{"require": {"google/apiclient": "1.0.*@beta"}}
```

to

```
{"require": {"google/apiclient": "2.0.*"}}
```

and then execute `php composer.phar update` (make sure you give right path for `.phar` file)

Answer (score 0):

Now it is deprecated and moved to Sub Google directory. Following is the new default path:
`google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\autoload.php`

Answer (score 0):

After following what Durandal had posted I tried it, but the new path for me is :

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php';
```

Once I made this changed it worked. Thanks for the help.