# Cannot find out what's wrong with my require_once call to YouTube API

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the google API as long as some other API but it seems that there is no way to make it work.

I get the error message

```
Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/msc/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-posts/lib/Google/Service/YouTube.php on line 32
```

The whole site is under wordpress 4,1,1

thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to turn error reporting on...

Comment: Turn on error_reporting and see which errors you have, perhaps you don't have the last file in that directory or with that name.

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in /home/msc/www/wp-content/plugins/wp-posts/lib/Google/Service/YouTube.php on line 32

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer was simple enough

I added

```
require_once 'Google/autoload.php';
```

based on this topic :

[Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351680/implementing-oauth2-login-fatal-error-class-google-service-not-found)

Comment: I get the same error above, but, to make this tricky, in the github repo I downloaded I cannot find Google/autoload.php - ref: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client - any idea how to find that file or fix? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an include path that points to where the /Google folder is

```
set_include_path('C:/path/to');
```