# Connecting to the Google Analytics API

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I am trying to connect to the Google Analytics api. My ultimate goal is to add a goal automatically, but I cannot even HelloAnalytics to work. I have followed the explicit tutorial [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api).

My require once did not work at first because the tutorial links to paths that cannot be found. So I had to make a guess at which files to link to. I tried the following:

```
require_once '/classes/google-api-php/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once '/classes/google-api-php/src/Google/Service/Analytics.php';
```

I then get the following error:

Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-test\classes\google-api-php\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php on line 32

I have a feeling the tutorial needs to be updated to match the library. At the moment I am stuck confused.

Comment: Hello Analytics php is out of date it uses the old version of the client library.   try this http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-php/

Comment: thank you for the suggestion. i will give it a go and get back to you

Comment: Hi. I am getting the same error :-( Fatal error: Class 'Google_Service' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\google-api-test\classes\src\Google\Service\Analytics.php on line 32

Comment: I have found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351680/implementing-oauth2-login-fatal-error-class-google-service-not-found

It says to use this line:

require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

It works and allows me to connect and "Login". But no data is being displayed.

Comment: SOLVED: The author of the post: daimto.com/google-oauth2-php , has replied to a comment. She has updated the post. It now works. I receive data back.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: The author of the post: [daimto.com/google-oauth2-php](http://daimto.com/google-oauth2-php) , has replied to a comment. She has updated the post. It now works. I receive data back.