# Fatal error: Class 'Google\Auth\OAuth2' not found

Tags: php, authentication

I am trying to implement sign in google plus.Actually I am learning these things.Please he;p me solve this issue.I know this question is already posted in SOF, but there is no an exact solution.

> Fatal error: Class 'Google\Auth\OAuth2' not found

```
<?php 
            require_once __DIR__.'/gpluslib/vendor/autoload.php';
            const CLIENT_ID = 'id';
            const CLIENT_SECRET = 'secret';
    const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost/home.php' ;
    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
    $client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
    $client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
    $client->setScopes('email');

    $plus = new Google_Service_Plus($client);

    if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
        session_unset();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
        $_session['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://'.$_server['HTTP_Host'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];   
        header('Location'.filter_var($redirect,FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']){
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
        $me = $plus->people->get('me');
        $id = $me['id'];
        $name = $me['displayName'];

        }else{
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
        }


    ?>
    <div>
    <?php 
       if(isset($authUrl)){
        echo "<a class='login' href='". $authUrl ."'><img src='dd.png' />";

          }
          else{
            print "ID:{$id} <br>";
            print "Name: {$name} ";
          }


    ?>
        </div>
```

Comment: you are creating an object of `Google_Client();` but I didn't see that you included class for `Google_Client();`. Either you forgot to include the class or it is not your full code.

Comment: How to include that ?

Comment: just like you include `require_once __DIR__.'/gpluslib/vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: can you say the exact location where it will be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Oauth2 login, Fatal error: Class 'Google\_Service' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351680/implementing-oauth2-login-fatal-error-class-google-service-not-found)

Comment: it is your code. You have batter knowledge where it is in your project folder.